# Missing exitsing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

from my view

```
 workshop/app/views/administration/dashboards/show.html.haml
```

I render the partial

```
   = render :partial =>  "administration/dasboards/activity_list"
```

but I am getting a missing template :

```
Missing partial administration/dasboards/activity_list with {:locale=>[:fr], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
 * "/Users/yves/github/local/workshop/app/views"
```

however I have in my structure

```
    views
       dashboards
         _activity_list.html.haml
```

I tried to render another view from another controller and it works ..
what could be wrong  ?  ( in dev environment... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo error, you are writing `dasboards instead of`dashboards`, also your structure should be:

```
views
  administration
    dashboards
      _activity.html.haml
```

and if the partial is in the same folder then your could simply do

`= render 'activity_list'`

Comment: Thanks I guess I was tired ... the structure was correct but  typo error as you stated ...